# Check my proof by contradiction...

Tags: proof-writing, proof-verification

The question is to prove the following by contradiction.

**There does not exist a smallest positive non-zero rational number.**

What I tried...

There does exist a smallest positive non-zero rational number.

Let that number be $p \in\mathbb Q$.

Divide $p$ by any positive, rational number $q$ : q > p for p => 1, q > 1 for p < 1.

Now... $\frac{p}{q}$ results in an infinite set of numbers that are smaller than $p$. There doest not exist a smallest positive non-zero       rational number.

This works, but I'd look to see what corrections I could make?

Comment: So, if $q=\frac{1}{2}$, then is $p/q<p$? You don't need infinitely many smaller positive rationals, you only need one smaller positive rational number.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware that only a single counter-example is needed for contradiction. Anything else?

Comment: Well, there is the problem that $p/q<p$ is not true for general rational $q$, which was the first question I asked, @Jennifer.

Comment: Yes, dividing by half was my initial answer... but that seemed boring. I've changed the conditions. They may still not be perfect.

Comment: How do you know dividing by $2$ results in a smaller number?

Comment: Conditions edited.

Comment: The logic is fine, but you've eschewed simplicity for... breadth(?) which is a stylistic issue I don't think many would agree with. Just divide $p$ by any integer $q > 1$ and you have a single contradiction, which proves the same thing but is simpler.

Answer (score 0):

An easier way:

Suppose $p\in\mathbb Q_{>0}$ the smallest positif non-zero rational. Then, $[0,p[\cap\mathbb Q_{>0}=\emptyset$ and this is in contradiction with $\overline{\mathbb Q_{>0}}=\mathbb R^+$.

Comment: Easier than replacing $p$ by $p/2$? [I doubt that](http://youtu.be/JRLNdcmRcFY?t=0m35s).

Comment: Except this proof is hardly "easier," since it requires an external entity, $\mathbb R$, the notion of closure, and you'd still need the same fact for $\mathbb R^+$ to give the result.

Comment: you guys are right. Shall I erase this post ?

Comment: I like it. I wanted to see other ways.